# Will this question be done via the Greedy Approach?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, greedy

I recently encountered a question asking :-

1. Maximum capacities of 2 bags are given (W1 and W2)
2. No of goods to carry in the bag are given (n)
3. The individual weights of the goods are given in the form of an array (x1,x2,x3....xn)

We need to maximize the weights that the 2 bags will carry, so that whatever weight is left with us to carry by ourselves is the minimum

So just needed to confirm that will this question be done using the greedy approach ? where we select the option first which gives us the maximized result ? Can anyone give any opinion ?

Comment: You might want to look at 0-1 Knapsack problem for reference

Comment: Yes it is similar to the 0-1 knapsack problem, the question actually is :-

There are 2 drones given with their maximum capacity and some goods are given with their weights which Walmart needs to send over these drones to customers. So we need to put the maximum no of weights on these drones so that we are left with minimum weight given the maximum capacity of the drones.

Comment: Simple example. W1 and W2 are 4. The individual weights are 3,3,2,2,2,2. If you start by putting the 3's in the bags, none of the 2's fit, and you have 8 left over. But if you put the 2's in the bags, then only the 3's are left, so you have 6 left over.

Comment: No, there is no greedy algorithm for this type of problem.